# How to add Google Authenticator (TOTP) to a Google account?

Tags: google-account, multi-factor-auth, google-authenticator

I'd like to 2FA with Google Authenticator to my Google account using the account settings page, but when I want to add 2FA, Google only offers adding an U2F security token for 2FA but provides no TOTP option. Following the instructions on the [official help page](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1066447?hl=en), I get only the options:

- SMS
- Security Key (U2F)
- Prompt (on a Android device)

How do I get Google to allow me to add a TOTP authenticator to the account?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add more details like brand, model, name and version of operative system of your mobile device. Include screenshots.

Comment: Also please search this site thoroughly and add what you found and why it don't meet your needs.

Comment: The question was asked on security stackexchange and only migrated to web applications. I am not using a mobile device at all, but the Firefox browser. The options seem to be the same for different browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The part of the migration is not really needed as it is already in the quesiton history. I followed the link in the question unsing Chrome, I saw a big blue button to install Google Authenticator. Have you already installed Google Autheticator in your device?

Comment: @Rubén The authenticator app is independent from the problem. When a site provides TOTP, it displays a QR code and you scan it with your authenticator app. Afterward you enter one of the codes generated by the app to prove that you successfully imported the TOTP key. The problem here is, that Google offers three 2FA options, but the one documented on their help page is not listed as an option.

Comment: Please [edit] the question question to clarify what is being asked. Make sure that what you say in the question mathes the linked resources.

Comment: This post  is unlocked but it still needs to be improved.

Comment: I think the duplicate you've found may be right. At least it describes the same symptoms. So there is probably no solution than waiting if Google will realize that 2FA with SMS is a bad idea and allow to add TOTP without also using SMS.